# nohup: trailing "&" prevents writing to output file?

Tags: nohup

Version 1 fails to write to my output.txt file:

`nohup python test.py &> output.txt &`

But Version 2 works:

`nohup python test.py &> output.txt`

I need the trailing `&` because I want to do other tasks on the command line!

Comment: Check with something simpler, for example `ls`: does `nohup ls &> output.txt &` write the output file? If yes, then debug your program or read the documentation of your Python interpreter. For example, it may be the case that adding `< /dev/null` will help. If not, then maybe your shell does not understand `&>`.

Comment: My program has no bugs as version 2 writes successfully to output file. (see original post).
`nohup ls &> output.txt &` does successfully write to output file too. So it appears something very strange is going on with python's interaction with `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: `... python -u ...` was the answer. Seems this additional option prevents Python output buffering.